# why does this comment create a compile error on Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, erb

there is a line displayed within <pre>

```
<%= h @stories.inspect %>
```

and the output was too long, so i changed it to

```
<%= #h @stories.inspect %>

<% @stories.each do |s| %>
  <%= h s.inspect %>
<% end %>
```

(commenting out the first line).  now the code will fail to compile... saying

compile error
/Users/winterheat/ror/shov2/app/views/stories/index.html.erb:13: syntax error, unexpected kENSURE, expecting ')'
/Users/winterheat/ror/shov2/app/views/stories/index.html.erb:15: syntax error, unexpected kEND, expecting ')'

and if i remove that commented line altogether, the code will work.  i thought in some book, it is said that you can comment out some code in ERB like that?

**Update:**  funny if i change it to

```
<% #h @stories.inspect %>
```

then it will compile fine... so the displaying of result tag <%= %> doesn't like comments, it seems.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Think of <%= as meaning "add the value of this expression to the output stream". No expression? Syntax error.

Consider

```
output << @stories.inspect
```

vs

```
output <<
```

Tracking down how <%= is really handled in the erb source may be edifying. I found it worth the effort when I was getting started with Rails.

Comment: but if puts "hello" and puts can both be handled without error, why not <%= # comment %> ?

Comment: Because that's an implementation detail specific to puts and has nothing to do with ERB?

Answer (score 4):

The proper way to comment a `<%= %>` tag in Ruby/Rails is `<%#= %>` ... place the comment sign before the equals sign. Then everything will work like a charm.

Answer (score 3):

<%= should be followed by a Ruby expression and is  replaced with result.

no expression leads to an error

Answer (score 1):

use

```
<% #h @stories.inspect %>
```

instead of

```
<%= #h @stories.inspect %>
```

because

```
<%= (I expect something that I can convert to string) %>
```